# Bootstrap JavaScript not working for rails 6

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have a starter project in rails 6 and I have added bootstrap to work with. I followed many tutorials including many discussions on implementing bootstrap with rails6 but I am not able to get bootstrap javaScript to work. I have added a basic navbar with dropdown, bootstrap is working but the dropdown is not working cant figure out what is wrong here. Please help.
Note: I have tried all tutorials on getting my bootstrap to work with rails6.Only the javascript part is not working.
This is just one of the tutorial I tried none is working though
https://www.vic-l.com/setup-bootstrap-in-rails-6-with-webpacker-for-development-and-production
Here is my GitHub repo please feel free to check it out and help me .
https://github.com/sriramhegdeofficial/RubyGems101

Comment: You'll need to describe what you mean by not being able to get bootstrap javascript to work. What are the steps to reproduce the issue you're having?